# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shift'

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I've search for this same issue and I think i know why this is happening but don't know how to solve it.

I have a dataframe (df) with x values.  I'm experimenting with np.vectorize in build on a much more complex logic but for now I'm testing this code below out and its firing an error most likely because the condition is looking for the previous value of x using shift() which if you start from the first row there won't be one. So i get the Nonetype error on line

```
 def cond(x):
        if x.shift(1)==1:
           return 'a'
        else:
          return 'b'

func = np.vectorize(cond)

foo = func(df["xValue"])

df["xValue"] = foo
```

Comment: What does your `df` contain?  dtypes etc?  `np.vectorize` applies your function to the elements of the argument one at a time.  In the case of a dataframe that would be `df.values`, an array.  What kind of object is supposed to have a `shift` method?  The error indicates that there are `None` objects in your dataframe.

Comment: It tried it with a random list of integers.  So when it would be AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'shift'.  shift() is the pandas.shift im trying to use.

Comment: somthing like this- df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCX'))

Comment: `vectorize` applies the function to individual elements or cells of the dataframe (or array derived from it).  `df.shift` or `df["xValue"].shift` works, `df['xValue'][0].shift` does not.

Comment: thanks for the response hpaul.  but since im passing df["xValue"] to the cond() function that applies the .shift I guess i can't use it that way? Is that because the shift() applies to the whole series xValue?

Comment: What is `x.shift(1)==1`  supposed to do?  `shift` applied to a column shifts the elements down a row, filling in the first with `nan`.  Try it yourself. Based a limited read of its docs and this experimenting, the `==` test doesn't make sense.

Comment: what im trying to do is assign a value to the current row based on the previous row value.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [272]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
In [273]: df
Out[273]: 
    A   B   C
0  13   5  45
1  28  41  89
2  63  87  46
3  53  81  54
4  26  82  46
In [274]: df['A']=df['A'].shift(1)
In [275]: df
Out[275]: 
      A   B   C
0   NaN   5  45
1  13.0  41  89
2  28.0  87  46
3  63.0  81  54
4  53.0  82  46
```

Here I shift 'A' down 1, and fill in the top hole with `nan` - which changes the dtype of the column to float.

Sounds like you want to apply your `cond` function to the elements after shift.  That is, do the column shift, and then pass them to `cond`:

```
In [277]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
In [278]: df
Out[278]: 
    A   B   C
0  18  59  16
1  69  85  41
2  53  91  37
3   8  22  17
4  10  90  26
In [279]: def cond(x):
     ...:     if x<50: return 'a'
     ...:     return 'b'

In [280]: func = np.vectorize(cond)
In [281]: func(df['A'])    # cond applied to column A
Out[281]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'],
      dtype='<U1')
In [282]: func(df['A'].shift(1))   # applied to column A after shift
Out[282]: 
array(['b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
      dtype='<U1')
In [283]: df['A']=_     # now assign those values back to A
In [284]: df
Out[284]: 
   A   B   C
0  b  59  16
1  a  85  41
2  b  91  37
3  b  22  17
4  a  90  26
```

I think there's a `pandas.apply` that works as well, but I know numpy better.

Comment: it more like if x > x(1) then x else none

Comment: I just chose a test that would give more variety than `==1`.

Comment: Thanks hpaul the current row assignment is dependent on the previous row value.   Much like a max or min function